# Copying data between tables with columns of different data types in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have over 100 `.csv` files which I imported/bulk loaded into SQL Server, all columns are of type `nvarchar(255)`. Now I have over 100 tables in the database.

Only after doing that, I got pre-defined SQL creation scripts for the same tables with selected and pre-defined columns data types, e.g datetime, decimal, int, etc..

My question here: is there fast way to copy the data from the bulk tables to the pre-defined ones? The insert won't work because of the conflict between the datatypes. Tried to alter tables/columns for changing the character lengths for columns of `nvarchar` types and it works fine/fast. The challenge is with the rest of the columns and with the data conversion, the tables have over 1000 columns altogether.

Comment: You're asking is there is any way to convert automatically? SQL will certainly try but it will fail with errors that only you can solve. For example is the date 01/03/2018 1st March or 3rd January? Do you want to automatically truncate data that won't fit into the target field? If you insert a varchar field that _only_ contains numeric data into an `INT` field it'll work fine. What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: You will need `cast` or `convert` and `case` to handle anomalies. But an 'Insert into table2 (col, col, col) select cast(col as type), col, col) from table1` should work if you are careful and the data isn't a basket case.

Comment: If you have all the column data type mapping information in some kind of database table or even a spreadsheet, a programmer could use that to automate writing an Insert with all the conversion statements.....   then that just becomes a programming logic question.

Comment: (note that if you have already created both sets of tables,  you do already have the column information in the database metadata....  you would just need to identify which pairs of tables go together,  in a programmatic way)